# Table shows Hive partition in CLI but it is not accessible through terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I use the command show partitions, I can see the date partitions in Hive. However when I try to access the folder through the hadoop fs -ls /path/to/partition I get the message No such file or directory.

I'm not sure why is this the case?
Shouldn't I be able to go to that date partition folder even if there is not data in it (I'm also not able to move data to this partition)

Comment: Can you provide your complete steps from creating table. How you are doing? Have you added the partition after creating partitioned table. You should add the partition after creating table command is : ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD PARTITION (dt='20151505').

Answer (score 3):

You have to follow as below:

**To create managed/internal table**

```
CREATE TABLE stations( number STRING, latitude INT, longitude INT, elevation INT, name STRING, country STRING) PARTITIONED BY (year int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE; 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "/home/cloudera/Desktop/Stations_2014.csv" INTO TABLE stations PARTITION(year=2014);
```

**To create external table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_stations( number STRING, latitude INT, longitude INT, elevation INT, name STRING, country STRING) PARTITIONED BY (year int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/hive/external/';

ALTER TABLE external_stations ADD PARTITION (year=2014);

hadoop fs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/Stations_2014.csv /user/hive/external/year=2014/
```

Comment: Yes the tables are already created with the external create table command. Is it possible to delete the folder with the hadoop command and the partition to still show up in the list in Hive CLI?

Comment: you have to create directory using hadoop command and then alter partition, then move the file from local to hadoop location of hive table

Comment: Thanks. I created the directory in hdfs and moved the data and it was visible in Hive CLI. I thought the HDFS folder partitions would also be created when the partitions were created in the external hive table.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a external partitioned table in Hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
 attribute INT,
 attribute1 STRING,
 attribute2 STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (datepart STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/user/hdfs/data/';
```

Here datepart is your partition.Once you have created the partitioned table then you need to add partition.using `ALTER TABLE`. Query will be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD PARTITION(datepart='20150515');
```

Then do `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hdfs/data/` you will get a directory named `datepart=20150515` under `/user/hdfs/data/` directory.
`datepart=20150515` this is your partitioned directory and hence your directory structure will be `/user/hdfs/data/datepart=20150515/`

Now you can load data into this directory using `hdfs dfs -put` command from local file system.
If your data is already available in HDFS location then you can use `LOAD DATA INPATH` command to load data into partitioned table
or you can use `hdfs dfs -mv` command to move data from hdfs location to another hdfs location.

Suppose if you want to drop a partition then you can use query like this.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(datepart=20150515);
```